# Request interception in Rust

Tags: rust, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am trying to get each request that browser sends and print it.
I found a crate headless_chrome and tried to use it, but so far was unsuccessful figuring out how to do it. If you know any other crate or way how to do it in rust, please let me know. Any and all help will be appreciated.

This is my code so far, I tried enabling request listener, but it requires `Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync>` and I couldn't figure out how to create it so far and I didn't get past it. I am missing the code which does something with the requests as well.

Edit: I found out that I need to return a RequestPausedDecision, but still dont know how to do it

```rs
use std::sync::Arc;

use anyhow::Result;
use headless_chrome::browser::tab::RequestInterceptor;
use headless_chrome::browser::tab::Tab;
use headless_chrome::protocol::cdp::types::Event;
use headless_chrome::protocol::cdp::IndexedDB::RequestData;
use headless_chrome::protocol::cdp::Page;
use headless_chrome::Browser;

#[tokio::main]
async fn request_interceptor_function(mut url: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let browser = Browser::default()?;

    let tab = browser.new_tab()?;

    tab.navigate_to(
        "https://animeheaven.ru/watch/the-ancient-magus-bride-season-2.55921?ep=183710",
    )?;
    println!("Navigated to website");
    // Arc<Transport>, SessionId, RequestPausedEvent
    const req_interceptor: Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> = Arc::new(
        |transport: Arc<transport::Transport>,
         session_id: SessionId,
         intercepted_req: RequestPausedEvent| {

        },
    );
    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    let url = "https://www.example.com";
    request_interceptor_function(title.to_string());
}
```

This is the edited version thanks to comments

```rs
use anyhow::Result;
use headless_chrome::browser::tab::RequestInterceptor;
use headless_chrome::browser::tab::RequestPausedDecision;
use headless_chrome::browser::transport::SessionId;
use headless_chrome::browser::transport::Transport;
use headless_chrome::protocol::cdp::Fetch::events::RequestPausedEvent;
use headless_chrome::Browser;
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct PrintingInterceptor {}

impl RequestInterceptor for PrintingInterceptor {
    fn intercept(
        &self,
        _transport: Arc<Transport>,
        _session_id: SessionId,
        event: RequestPausedEvent,
    ) -> RequestPausedDecision {
        let url = event.params.request.url.as_str();
        println!("{}", url);
        RequestPausedDecision::Continue(None)
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn request_interceptor_function(url: &str) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("Navigating to website");

    let browser = Browser::default()?;
    let tab = browser.new_tab()?;

    let request_interceptor: Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> =
        Arc::new(PrintingInterceptor {});

    tab.navigate_to(url)?;
    tab.wait_until_navigated()?;
    println!("Navigated to website");
    tab.enable_request_interception(request_interceptor)?;

    println!("Enabled request interception");

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let url = "https://animeheaven.ru/watch/the-ancient-magus-bride-season-2.55921?ep=183710";
    let res = request_interceptor_function(url);
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`RequestInterceptor`](https://docs.rs/headless_chrome/1.0.5/headless_chrome/browser/tab/trait.RequestInterceptor.html) is a trait that you can implement. You must define a type, implement the trait for that type, and put a value of that type in the `Arc`.

Something like this should work. (I have not compiled this code, so there may be small mistakes.)

```rust
let request_interceptor: Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> =
    Arc::new(PrintingInterceptor {});
```

```rust
struct PrintingInterceptor {}

impl RequestInterceptor for PrintingInterceptor {
    fn intercept(
        &self,
        transport: Arc<Transport>,
        session_id: SessionId,
        event: RequestPausedEvent
    ) -> RequestPausedDecision {
        let url = event.params.request.url.as_str();
        println!("{url}");
        RequestPausedDecision::Continue(None)
    }
}
```

If your interceptor needs additional data to work, put it as fields in the `struct`.

Comment: thank you, I have tried using this code and it shows no error, but it doesnt print any requests urls, I have tried enabling it with     ```tab.enable_request_interception(request_interceptor)?;```
 It runs, shows no error and ends but doesn't intercept the requests and prints nothing.

Comment: @DanielVaško I'm not familiar with this library and was just answering a basic Rust usage question. That said, if nothing is printed then it must be that the interceptor is not being called. I notice that in your code you are not installing the interceptor until _after_ you've done `navigate_to()`. Perhaps you should install the interceptor first rather than last.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with this package for a couple of days (originally i had the same problem and unfortunately i have 0 experience with Rust and Chrome DevTools Protocol) i figure out that you need to enable certain domains for CDP (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-enable) to receive the events from the WS channel.

You need to add this before `enable_request_interception` to make your interceptor work:

```
tab.enable_fetch(None, None)?;
```